# How to properly give individual users access to individual directories in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, permissions

*TL;DR:* Windows 8.1 multi-user machine, external hard drive `E:` containing subdirectories `E:\user_1`, `E:\user_2`, `...`, `E:\user_n`, etc. I want to ensure that `user_i` can access files on `E:` if and only if they're in directory `user_i`, but I want to do this in time `O(n)` and not `O(n^2)` (the `O(n^2)` solution involves explicitly denying `user_i` access to directory `user_j` if `i!=j`).

---

I do not understand permissions on Windows machines at all and I want to understand them properly so that I don't have to ask 10 questions here. I tried Google first, but to my genuine surprise Google (and even Bing) takes me to [old documentation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/what-are-permissions), which don't seem to have a Windows 8 as an option, and it's Windows 8 I'm interested in.

I know what permissions are, I just don't know how to get them to work in a sane manner in what is surely a very standard set-up -- which I'll describe now.

I administer (very poorly, currently) a Windows 8.1 machine in my home, with a very full `C:` drive where the operating system is installed, and also an `E:` drive where I want to enable my users (a.k.a. my family) to put their data (their `Dropbox` directories, for example). The set-up is this: all users (including me) have local standard non-admin user account, and we have one admin account called `PC` that usually no-one logs into but I have the password.

I can right-click on files/directories and click the `Security` tab. If I do that I see a frustratingly small sub-window called `Group or user names`, which contains a list of groups and user names, typically longer than the size of the sub-windows and I don't know how to resize it, but that's not important right now.

My question is this. If I want users (e.g `Dad`, `Mum`, `Kid1`, `Kid2`, etc.) to be able to store private data on the drive `E:` in subdirectories called `E:\Dads_stuff`, `E:\Mums_stuff`, etc., then:

1. Who should be the owner of drive `E:` (and does this even matter?) Can I change permissions for the owner?
2. Who should be the owner of the subdirectories?
3. What permissions should be set on drive `E:`
4. What permissions should be set on the subdirectories?

Windows 8 seems very keen on giving me access to permissions for groups that I am not interested in, like `Users`. Seeing as I want some users to have different permissions to other users I am particularly unclear about how these should be set. Logically it seems to me that the `Users` group should have full control of `E:\Dads_stuff`, because if it doesn't then I, `Dad`, as a user, inherit the problems. On the other hand I don't want my kids deleting stuff in my `Dropbox` -- but with my current understanding the only way I can see of preventing this happening is by either setting up a group containing everyone-but-me and denying access to this group, or individually editing the access properties of every user on the machine denying everyone but me access to `E:\Dads_stuff`. This can't be the right way to do it because what if I have 7 kids with another one on the way? I shouldn't have to be editing default permissions for loads of directories every time my wife gives birth; I have other things to do.

There are lots of Windows 8 permissions questions here already, but many of them have very few upvotes and seem to be just general users being frustrated about different questions, so here I am.

Comment: The documentation you linked to is current.  What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Using windows you dont will usually use whitelist method or blacklist method but never both. Whitelist means you add users you want to grand the permission and remove all other users from the list. Blacklist you give all users access to the folder and add deny to users you dont want to access the folder. I would allways prefere whitelist. Btw. But i see here an issue because your drive is an external drive. if you connect it to any other device you will usually be able to get the rights to access all folders unless you use some encryption.

Comment: If there are a lot of users you work with you should use groups because when the Access Control lists are getting biger it will take longer to figure out the permission for a single user. BTW deny right is allways stronger than permit and if the user is not listed in the ACL he has no rights to access that folder

Comment: @Ramhound: because it says "Windows 7" in the top right of the page if I follow that link, and the only option in the associated drop-down menu for me is to switch it to Vista. If I click the link I am redirected to http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/what-are-permissions#1TC=windows-7, which surprises me because I'm on an 8.1 machine. That's what makes me think otherwise. I should say that I have very little experience with the windows docs but this did seem a little counterintuitive to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

> Who should be the owner of drive E: (and does this even matter?)

The owner should be the `Administrator` user.

> Can I change permissions for the owner?

As an Administrator you can change the permissions of any file.

> Who should be the owner of the subdirectories?

The owner of the files in this case ( Mom, Dad, Kid1, Kid2, etc.. )

> What permissions should be set on drive E:

The default permissions on the root directory is fine.

> What permissions should be set on the subdirectories?

Change it so that only the owner can access the folder.

I personally would create new user Groups with the permissions you do want to give then assign users to those new groups since a single User group doesn't seem to fit your usage.

**You only have to set the ownership and permissions once per folder then allow Windows to recursively set the permissions.**  You could also do this through Powershell if you wanted.

Since this drive is an external drive, if its connected to another computer, you wouldn't be able to access any folder without first taking ownership of all the folders/files.

Comment: Do not forget to remove recursive permission from the parent folder.

Comment: @IvanViktorovic - When I perform a recursive command I target the top most folder I want to provide permission to.

Comment: @IvanViktorovic - Feel free to add anything you think I missed.

Comment: I know but when you create a new folder it ussualy takes the same rights as the parent and unless you deacticvate this and copy (or remove) the rights you wont be able to change any rights.But it depends on how the parent drive or folder is set up

Comment: This answer doesn't quite make sense to me yet. If I want to deny access to everyone-but-owner, I might, say, deny access to Users but then give access to Owner, but because Owner is a User Owner won't be allowed access. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my own question. What was confusing me was that I didn't know whether "Users" should be set to Allow (so all users could see other users' stuff) or Deny (so then not even the user who wants to see their own stuff can see it). I couldn't see a sensible choice for permissions for Users. But in Windows the answer seems to be that you simply don't even answer the question for Users -- you just delete the option in Properties/Security. I find this a bit of a strange way to do things but it seems to work and probably it's the normal Windows approach.